# google sheet to pdf mailto

Tags: pdf, button, google-sheets

i changed the coding so far that i'm now able to send a spread sheet to a email address. What i'm looking for now is the possibility to select a specific range like (A1:J23) and send only that range to my mail address. any ideas what i'm doing wrong here? Always getting the warning: 
TypeError: Cannot find function getSheets in object Range. (line 8, file

```
function onOpen() {
var submenu = [{name:"einreichen", functionName:"sendEmailWithPdfAttach"}];
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('E-mail senden', submenu);  
}

var range    = 'A1:J23'
var source   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(range);
var subject  = source.getSheets()[0].getRange('B3').getValue();
var body     = source.getSheets()[0].getRange('F3').getValue();
var sheetNum = 0; // first sheet(tab) is zero, second sheet is 1, etc..  


function sendEmailWithPdfAttach() {
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var thema = source.getSheets()[0].getRange('D3').getValue();  // 
 var mailTo = source.getSheets()[0].getRange('E3').getValue(); // 'D46' cell        which consists an emailaddress.
 var name = source.getSheets()[0].getRange('C3').getValue();
 var sheets = source.getSheets();
 sheets.forEach(function (s, i) {
     if (i !== sheetNum) s.hideSheet();
 });
 var url = Drive.Files.get(source.getId())
     .exportLinks['application/pdf'];
 url = url + '&size=letter' + //paper size
     '&portrait=false' + //orientation, false for landscape
     '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
     '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' + //hide optional//     was false
     '&gridlines=false' + //false = hide gridlines
     '&fzr=false'; //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
 var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
     headers: {
         'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
     }
 });  

 MailApp.sendEmail(mailTo, subject, body, {
     attachments: [response.getBlob().setName(name)]
 });
 sheets.forEach(function (s) {
     s.showSheet();
 })
}
```

Comment: What language? What platform?

Comment: google sheet - google java script, Mac - Chrome

Comment: .getSheets() needs a spreadsheet object. At this moment 'source'  (line 7) is a range object. Don't no why you need 'global' variables any way.. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something that I used before from a script online, It should suit everything you asked for. Go to Tools, and go to script editor, paste this in, change the settings you need and save. Reload the sheet and you will see an extra option there.

```
//var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//function onOpen() {
//  var menu = [{name: "Email PDF", functionName: "emailSpreadsheetAsPDF"}];
//  ss.addMenu("Email PDF", menu);
//};



/* Send Spreadsheet in an email as PDF, automatically */
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {

  // Send the PDF of the spreadsheet to this email address
  var email = "kelvin@test.com

  // Subject of email message
  // The way it is formatted now is "Timesheet by (Get email of user who initiated the sending) and the time
  var now = new Date();
  var subject = "Time Sheet by " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + " " + (new Date()).toString(); 

  // Or use SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("<<SPREADSHEET URL>>");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  //var body = Choose what you want as the body message
  var body = "PDF generated by " + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() + " from " + ss.getName() + " on " + (new Date()).toString();


  var url = ss.getUrl();
  url = url.replace(/edit$/,'');

  /* Specify PDF export parameters
  // From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
    exportFormat = pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    gridlines = true / false
    printtitle = true (1) / false (0)
    size = legal / letter/ A4
    fzr (repeat frozen rows) = true / false
    portrait = true (1) / false (0)
    fitw (fit to page width) = true (1) / false (0)
    add gid if to export a particular sheet - 0, 1, 2,..
  */

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   // export as pdf
                + '&size=A4'                       // paper size
                + '&portrait=false'                    // orientation, false for landscape
                + '&fitw=true&source=kelvin'           // fit to width, false for actual size
                + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
                + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=False' // hide page numbers and gridlines
                + '&fzr=false'                         // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
                + '&fitw=true'                         // Fit to page width
                + '&gid=';                             // the sheet's Id


  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets(); 

  //make an empty array to hold your fetched blobs  
  var blobs = [];

  for (var i=0; i<sheets.length; i++) {

    // Convert individual worksheets to PDF
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheets[i].getSheetId(), {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  token
      }
    });

    //convert the response to a blob and store in our array
   var pdfBlob = blobs[i] = response.getBlob().setName(sheets[i].getName() + '.pdf');

  }

  //create new blob that is a zip file containing our blob array
// var zipBlob = Utilities.zip(blobs).setName(ss.getName() + '.zip'); 

  //optional: save the file to the root folder of Google Drive
//  DriveApp.createFile(pdfBlob);

  // Define the scope
//  Logger.log("Storage Space used: " + DriveApp.getStorageUsed());

  // If allowed to send emails, send the email with the PDF attachment
  if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0) 
     GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {attachments:[pdfBlob]});

}
```

Comment: cools so far. thanks, only that i have all sheets and i would need a button to send the mail, this version works as soon as i open the sheet.

Comment: This works only if you press the "Email PDF" menu. it does not send email to moment it's open.

Comment: If you could mark it as the correct answer, that would help me great.

Comment: one more question. are you able to point out how i can include the code so i'm able to select a certain sheet in my Spreadsheet?

Comment: You can change the GID to the sheet you want. Please check the 
`var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' ` part you will see '&gid='  just put the number 0,1,2,3 for the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

So thats the solution i was i able to find on the internet, with the help of Kelvin and try and error by myself. it works now on my behalf. Because it was so hard to find i wanted to post the final result for somebody who is looking for something like this.

```
 function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Send summary', 'menuItem1')
      .addSeparator()      
      .addItem('Send summary&Week', 'menuItem2')
      .addToUi();
}

function menuItem1() {

var source   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var subject  = source.getSheets()[9].getRange('G1').getValue(); //cell for     subject in sheet
var body     = source.getSheets()[9].getRange('F1').getValue(); 
var sheetNumSummary = 9; // first sheet(tab) is zero, second sheet is 1, etc..

    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var thema = source.getSheets()[9].getRange('f3').getValue();  // 
    var mailTo = ('youremailaddress@here.com'); //source.getSheets()    [0].getRange('D1').getValue(); // 'D1' cell which consists an emailaddress.
    var name = source.getSheets()[9].getRange('G1').getValue(); // Name of     Attachement
    var sheets = source.getSheets();
    sheets.forEach(function (s, i) {
        if (i !== sheetNumSummary) s.hideSheet();
    });
    var url = Drive.Files.get(source.getId())
        .exportLinks['application/pdf'];
    url = url + '&size=letter' + //paper size
        '&portrait=false' + //orientation, false for landscape
        '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
        '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' + //hide optional
        '&gridlines=false' + //false = hide gridlines
        '&fzr=false'; //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });

    MailApp.sendEmail(mailTo, subject, body, {
        attachments: [response.getBlob().setName(name)]
    });
    sheets.forEach(function (s) {
        s.showSheet();
    })
}


function menuItem2() {

var source   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var subject  = source.getSheets()[9].getRange('G1').getValue();
var body     = source.getSheets()[9].getRange('F1').getValue(); 
var sheetNumSummary = 9; // first sheet(tab) is zero, second sheet is 1, etc..

    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var thema = source.getSheets()[9].getRange('f3').getValue();  // 
    var mailTo = ('youremailaddress@here.com'); //source.getSheets()    [0].getRange('D1').getValue(); // 'D1' cell which consists an emailaddress.
    var name = source.getSheets()[9].getRange('G1').getValue(); // Name of     Attachement
    var sheets = source.getSheets();
    sheets.forEach(function (s, i) {
        if (i !== sheetNumSummary) s.hideSheet();
    });
    var url = Drive.Files.get(source.getId())
        .exportLinks['application/pdf'];
    url = url + '&size=letter' + //paper size
        '&portrait=false' + //orientation, false for landscape
        '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
        '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' + //hide optional
        '&gridlines=false' + //false = hide gridlines
        '&fzr=false'; //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });

    MailApp.sendEmail(mailTo, subject, body, {
        attachments: [response.getBlob().setName(name)]
    });
    sheets.forEach(function (s) {
        s.showSheet();
    })

/*}
function menuItem2() {
*/

var source   = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var subject  = source.getSheets()[10].getRange('G1').getValue();
var body     = source.getSheets()[10].getRange('F1').getValue(); //bleibt leer, kein Text notwendig
var sheetNumWeek = 10; // first sheet(tab) is zero, second sheet is 1, etc..

    var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var thema = source.getSheets()[10].getRange('C1').getValue();  // 
    var mailTo = ('admin6142.c087880@m.evernote.com, Dwight@ndmarin.com');     //source.getSheets()[0].getRange('D1').getValue(); // 'D1' cell which consists an     emailaddress.
    var name = source.getSheets()[10].getRange('G1').getValue(); // Name of     Attachement
    var sheets = source.getSheets();
    sheets.forEach(function (s, i) {
        if (i !== sheetNumWeek) s.hideSheet();
    });
    var url = Drive.Files.get(source.getId())
        .exportLinks['application/pdf'];
    url = url + '&size=letter' + //paper size
        '&portrait=false' + //orientation, false for landscape
        '&fitw=true' + //fit to width, false for actual size
        '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=false' + //hide     optional// was false
        '&gridlines=false' + //false = hide gridlines
        '&fzr=false'; //do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });

        MailApp.sendEmail(mailTo, subject, body, {
            attachments: [response.getBlob().setName(name)]
        });
        sheets.forEach(function (s) {
            s.showSheet();
    })
}
```