# Google Sheet to PDF MailTo: Part 2

Tags: pdf, scripting, google-sheets

First-timer here trying to modify code to fit my needs without any coding training.  I borrowed the following [google sheet to pdf mailto script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34941585/7419758) from another poster (Kelvin Chong).

I am able to successfully send an email to myself with an attached PDF, but the PDF is blank.  I'm apparently missing something when it comes to the script retrieving the active spreadsheet.  The Google Sheet I am trying to send as a PDF is only a single sheet and I have tried both the `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()` and `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` options.  Neither method gives me an error when I run the script and, like I said, it emails me a PDF...it's just blank.  Oh, and yes, when running the openByUrl I did enter the URL of the spreadsheet and have checked to make sure it is open for anyone to view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...I figured it out through some trial and error.  Basically, the original programmer wrote the script so that it would send a zip file.  Another programmer modified the script so that it would only send an individual sheet.  When I started tinkering, I noticed that the zip file would have a blank page and then the actual pdf.  Once I realized this, I just tinkered a little with the code to only focus on that second sheet.  All is well now!